# SCHEME | lambda vs λ?

Tags: syntax, lambda, scheme, racket

I'm taking a SCHEME course, and I was wandering if there's any difference between writing "λ" or "lambda".
To clarify, is there a functional difference between these two snippets ?

Using λ

```
(define foo
 (λ (x)
   (...)))
```

Using lambda

```
(define bar 
 (lambda (x)
  (...)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`λ` is the lowercase symbol with the name `lambda` but most Scheme implementations doesn't have `λ` defined as a synonym for `lambda`. This the difference is that `lambda` is guaranteed to work while `λ` certainly is shorter for a teacher to write.

As an example I can mention that the wizards used `λ` quite often in the [SICP videos](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/) even though the symbol wasn't supported. Whenever you see it you need to write `lambda`.

Comment: So to get this straight in my head - "λ" in Dr.Racket is some kind of "IDE sugar" ?

Comment: No, more like syntax sugar in the #!racket language, the default language of racket application. In both #!r5rs and #!r6rs, even when running in racket, it's not defined and you get *λ: unbound identifier*